# Hiding and showing divs when user uses select box not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my website I allow the user to use a drop down to select various options, when they choose an option i have some jquery that should hide or show different pictures according to what they choose. However it doesn't seem to be changing.

I have created a js fiddle and put some

text in on the cook section to try and test it but it still isn't working. Can anyone see why?

http://jsfiddle.net/av7E2/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#select-portion').change(function () {
        $('.box').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.prepBox').hide();
    $('#option10').show();
    $('#select-prep-time').change(function () {
        $('.prepBox').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cookBox').hide();
    $('#cook1').show();
    $('#select-cook-time').change(function () {
        $('.cookBox').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
    });
```

Comment: Why have you got 3 different document ready calls? It would be much better to merge them all into one.

Comment: Can you add the markup here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your fiddle, select-cook-time is a class and not an id value. Hence you should be using .select-cook-time instead. Try this

```
$('.select-cook-time').change(function () {
        $('.cookBox').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your fiddle. You are using **#select-portion** when you should be using **.select-portion.** You seem to have the same problem with all other dropdowns.
Apply this changes and change handlers will be invoked.

$('#select-cook-time') ->  $('.select-cook-time')

$('#select-prep-time') ->  $('.select-prep-time')

$('#select-portion') ->  $('.select-portion')

Answer (score 0):

Well in your fiddle, you have class="select-portion" and in the jquery you are looking for # not .

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning up some of the typos in the markup and cleaning up the jQuery we get this -

```
$(document).ready(function () { // one document ready handler (although you can use as many as you'd like, this is just cleaner)
     $('.box, .prepBox, .cookBox').hide(); // combine selectors
     $('#option1, #option10, #cook1').show(); // combine selectors
     $('.select-portion').change(function () { // change to class selector
         $('.box').hide();
         $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
     $('.select-prep-time').change(function () { // change to class selector
         $('.prepBox').hide();
         $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
     $('.select-cook-time').change(function () { // change to class selector
         $('.cookBox').hide();
         $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
 });
```

You can see this in operation here - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/av7E2/1/